# Sharing link via facebook. Wrong title and description

Tags: android, facebook, share

I have problem with Facebook share dialog. I'm trying to share link to my app on Play Store.

```
    FacebookDialog facebookDialog = new FacebookDialog.ShareDialogBuilder(context)
                        .setLink(googlePlayLink)
                        .setPicture(imageLink)
                        .setDescription("description")
                        .setName("name")
                        .build();
                facebookDialog.present();
```

When dialog is opened everything is ok. I see "name" in title and "description" in description. But once I shared this link Facebook creates post with name of my app in title and "Get it on Google Play".

Is there way to put title and description I want?

Comment: Tell google to change the og:title and og:description on Google Play

Comment: It's already been reported as a bug: https://developers.facebook.com/bugs/398351583666605/